# Orchard CMS: How to update content item in command?

Tags: orchardcms

Want to update content item in command by code like following:

```
var item = _contentManager.Get(model.Id);
item.As<TitlePart>().Title = model.Title;
_contentManager.UpdateEditor(item, this);
```

But I have no editor in command. 
I can call Update method of all pars repositories, but it looks like wrong way, what is right way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `UpdateEditor`. The session should be saved when the command finishes (you can cancel this by calling `IOrchardServices.TransactionManager.Cancel()`).